# WordPress admin bar- How to add icons on front-end admin bar?

Tags: php, wordpress, admin

On my admin back-end i have caching options so every time i need to clear cache i need to go back to admin's dashboard.

What i am trying to do is to get this menu with tiger icon- http://clip2net.com/s/3CwV5KA

To show on my front-end-
http://clip2net.com/s/3CwV6NM

I tried to look trough other plugins i have and to search on Google but i couldn't find a solution or get this done :\

How can i add these icons to the admin-bar on my front-end please?
Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/172939/how-do-i-add-an-icon-to-a-new-admin-bar-item

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i did find out how to add icons/items to the admin bar but only from the back-end and not on the font-end while surfing my website